# Where should a default destructor C++11 style go, header or cpp?

Tags: c++11

In C++11 a default implementation of constructor(s), destructor and copy/move operators can be specified with "= default". Where to put the "= default", in header file, where the class definition is, or in the source file (cpp)?

In header file Test.h:

```
class Test
{
public:
    ~Test() = default;
};
```

In source file Test.cpp:

```
class Test
{
public:
    ~Test();
};

#include "Test.h"
Test::~Test() = default;
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do both:

- in the first case (header) the destructor will be considered as non-user defined
- in the second case (cpp) the compiler will consider it as user defined.

A user-provided destructor is non-trivial, making the class itself necessarily non-trivial.

Unless you have a good reason to for the second option, putting it in the header is the usual way to go.

Comment: Note that a _good_ reason to go for the second option might be the [Pimpl idiom](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl): if you wrap your `Impl` instance in a `std::unique_ptr`, then the default constructor cannot be instantiated in the class header file, because `Impl` class is incomplete at this point.

Answer (score 18):

I have to disagree with rubenvb. You aren't forced to put the explicit default destructor in the header file.
In fact, there is a use case for which it's perfectly valid (and necessary) to put the explicit default destructor in the .cpp file.

Consider the case where you forward declare a class in the header file, and use it with one of the smart pointers templates. As the implicit destructor doesn't have the complete declaration of the forward declared class, it cannot properly do its deletion. Therefore, you need to move the destructor definition to the C++ file, where you should have access to the complete declaration.

In *A.hpp*:

```
#pragma once
#include <memory>
class B;

class A 
{
private:
  std::unique_ptr<B> my_b;
public:
// ~A() = default; 
// defining the default destructor would fail as 
// class B is still a partial class here
  ~A();
};
```

In *A.cpp*:

```
#include "A.hpp"

// the previously forward declared class B is now included here
#include "B.hpp"

// we can use the default destructor here as B is
// no longer a partial class
A::~A() = default;
```

Answer (score 0):

You must put it in the header (well, wherever the class definition is located and the destructor is declared) or else anyone using your class won't know about this behaviour, including the compiler, which leads to obvious wrong behaviour on its part.

Comment: What? Do you imply that having member functions defined in implementation file (.cpp) makes the compiler have **obvious wrong behaviour**?